# Get files with time stamp (can be filtered by yesterday) from linux and compare with those files which in Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, bash

I need to compare which files are inserted into Oracle DB.

I have files of entire months in current directory. And everyday those files get inserted into DB. There is one table for storing file names which gets success fully inserted to DB. Somehow this process misses some files while inserting into DB. I want to check yesterday's files inserted properly into DB.So i am doing below

```
#!/bin/sh
export ORACLE_HOME=/home/oracle/product/11.2.0/db
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
user="username"
pass="userpass"

for i in {"FLD1","FLD2","FLD3","FLD4","FLD5","FLD6","FLD7"};
do
  yday=$(date --date="yesterday" +"%b %_d")
  names=$(ls /mypath/$i/ -ltr | grep "$yday" |  awk '{print $9}');
  for list in $names 
     do   
     sqlplus -S $user/$pass <<EOF
     insert into Myuser.DIR_LIST(file_name) values($list); 
     commit;
     EOF
     done
done  
...
Here i will compare to table and which not inserted table will be send by email.
...
```

but above script gives error:

```
line 19: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Comment: try using `<<-EOF` instead of `<<EOF` (Note the hyphen) to persist your indentation

Comment: it's same still gives error

Comment: it run okay when delete space between "<<EOF" and "insert  into". But i think it's not good method i want to a sqlplus outside of loop.

Comment: does it run fine without spaces before `insert into`? .. if yes, then it should work with `<<-EOF`

Comment: yes. it worked Now i would like to change algorithm otherwise it is taking a time to insert operation. like below

  sqlplus -s $user/$pass <<-EOF
for list in $names
do       
insert into myuser.DIR_LIST(file_name) values('$list'); 
done     
commit; 
EOF
done

Comment: change algorithm in what way? .. is your question solved?

Comment: yep. it solved but i think it will be better if i can find only one time connect to DB and commit after insert operation finish. Like how to use a loop in inside the EOF

Comment: i should have used plsql loop not shell loop, i got it. Is that right ?

Comment: yes thats right. (Its better to use plsql loop instead of bash loop to reduce num of connections)

Comment: please mark the answer and get the question solved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

contents of script.bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
#normal usage
cat <<EOF
abcd
xyz
EOF
echo "*************************"
#using heredoc without script indentation
if [[ true ]]; then
    cat <<EOF
abcd
xyz
EOF
fi
echo "*************************"
#using heredoc with script indentation
if [[ true ]]; then
    cat <<-EOF
    abcd
    xyz
    EOF
fi
```

Output:

```
$ ./script.bash 
abcd
xyz
*************************
abcd
xyz
*************************
abcd
xyz
$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@ritesht93, can you check my below script , where is my mistake ?
It seems PLSQL loop is not working coz of that $name variable wrong. PLSQl is not working same as shell loop. How do i pass this variable to PLSQL loop ? Should i use array ?

#!/bin/sh
export ORACLE_HOME=/home/oracle/product/11.2.0/db
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
user="username"
pass="password"
for i in for i in {"FLD1","FLD2","FLD3","FLD4","FLD5","FLD6","FLD7"};
do
  yday=$(date --date="yesterday" +"%Y%m%d")
  names=$(ls /mypath/$i/ -ltr | grep "$yday" |  awk '{print $9}');

sqlplus -s $user/$pass <<-EOF >log.log
set pagesize 0 feedback off verify off heading off echo off;
begin     
     forall j in $names 
     insert into Myuser.DIR_LIST(file_name) values(j); 
end;
commit;
/
EOF
done
```

Comment: you cant use `$names` to iterate inside oracle, you will need to convert bash array to oracle syntax